# Preload whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preload

I would like to preload everything before HTML even starts displaying.

The problem is with loading external fonts, images etc.

I was trying to make simple jquery function with:

CSS:

```
html { display:none; }
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('html').css('display', 'block');
});
```

But that doesn't really work.

The main reason that I want to preload is that I have font animation on the page start and when the font isn't loaded and CSS animation is fired it looks a little buggy.

Comment: So what does happen? Any errors? Try using `$(window).on('load', func...` since `load()` shortcut is deprecated

Comment: isn't `load()` used to load resources?

Comment: @LucaKiebel yes but without url string as first argument and function instead was also a  shortcut for load event

Comment: Works pretty well - thnx! Just need to adjust few more things, but think that is it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`load()` as a shortcut for `on('load')` is deprecated:

Try using

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('html').css('display', 'block');
});
```